# How to change user permissions at Hyper-V VM using C#

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I want to add/edit user permissions remotely at Hyper-V using C#. I know that WMI provider is helpful only for getting info from Hyper-V, but I need some solution for writing data to Hyper-V. Are there any ways to solve my problem?

Comment: FWIW there is an open-source library available to automate Hyper-V from .NET which wraps the WMI calls for you: http://hypervlib.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Dai I saw this project earlier but the functionality of this library is too poor. Only a couple of actions. But nevertheless thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don`t want relying on third party or alpha libraries, there is one way where C# is party involved: hyper v has a very good set of PowerShell commandlets. Just create a powershell script file with a parameter and run that script directly from C#. This should be an easy solution with full microsoft support. The command you might want to use would be

```
Grant-VMConnectAccess
```

See [Microsoft documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848559.aspx)

You can either call a Powershell Script from C# or include C# functions in the script. A good example for both ways can be found [here](http://executeautomation.com/blog/calling-c-code-in-powershell-and-vice-versa/)

Running a C# functions from PS

```
  Add-Type -TypeDefinition $CalcInstance
  $CalcInstance = New-Object -TypeName Calc
  $CalcInstance.Add(20,30)
```

Building a PS script object in C#

```
 var powerShell = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(someScript);
```

Of course this only works depending on your target scenario - powershell has to be installed on the machines running your C# application later.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this one!